# The bootstrap "dropdown open" toggle does not work properly in development, but works in production

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am following the [RailsTutorial sample_app](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code%3alayout_signin_signout_links) and inside we use the twitter-boostrap framework. There is a dropdown menu [(the code, jQuery)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js) that does not work for me properly in the development env, but works well in production (on Heroku).

With the help of "Visual Event" I confirmed that there is an event associated with the menu title. The normal behavior should be on click to change the class from:

```
<li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

to:

```
<li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown open">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

Still, in my case, on click it adds "open" and removes in the same moment. I could just barely noticed that it makes the change, but quickly return to the initial state and thus, the dropdown menu does not open.

If I manually edit the code in the browser and add "open" to the class, the menu opens. If I then click on the menu title, it removes "open" for a moment and then it returns it again (just opposite from the first case).

I am very puzzled that it works in production, but not in development (on the same browser). What should I check?

Thanks!

Vasil //with the first question

Answer (score 36):

You would get this behavior if you are loading the code for **bootstrap-dropdown.js** twice.  Check to make sure you are not loading both **bootstrap-dropdown.js** AND **bootstrap.js**.  The latter includes the former.

---

#### [JSFiddle FAIL](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/BjxwJ/)

If you remove the **bootstrap-dropdown.js** from the resources panel, and rerun it, it will work.

Comment: Came to this question for a different reason, but you helped me quickly identify my problem. Props.

Comment: In my case, I was loading UI-Bootstrap for Angular which has no dependency on bootstrap.js. Good catch merv!

Comment: Echoing @NickWoodhams comment, I too was including both UI-Bootstrap's ui-bootstrap-tpls.js and bootstrap.js and was getting the funny dropdown issue where I had to click a dropdown twice to get it to show.

Comment: In my case, I was including `datatable.min.js`, section `Bootstrap v3.3.5 (http://getbootstrap.com)`, at the same time with `bootstrap.min.js`. I modified `datatable.min.js` and deleted the section of Bootstrap. Thanks @merv

Comment: I experience this issue on Laravel. I am trying to learn it and apparently, the Bootstrap 3 JS and CSS is already included in the initial installation and I made a mistake of adding the JS again on my layout blade template.

Answer (score 4):

(Rails 3.2) I solved this problem by removing locally precompiled assets -- it would work fine in Heroku/Prod but would open and close instantly in dev.

`rake assets:clean`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it turned out that bootstrap drop downs were being loaded twice. +1 for this fix!

We load bootstrap-dropdown.js globally because we use it on every page. One of our devs loaded bootstrap.js into a widget as a dependency. The result was that our drop downs worked every page except one. It was a bit tough to track down, and it would have been a lot harder to figure out without the knowledge of what had changed on the page recently.

Answer (score 2):

update from bootstrap -v 2.1 to 2.3 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced almost same issue. But causes loading bootstrap and bootstrap.min js files at the same time in one HTML page as bundle (ASP.NET MVC project). Removing one of them was solved it.

Comment: i came here for searching for asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem. But all it happened was I missed some ending HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I learned that precompiled assets are used in development and production. I was testing caching in a production environment, and when I switched back to development, the dropdowns stopped working.

Always remember to clean out your compiled assets when switching back to development from production.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. Production mode was causing this issue. What I found through a ton of trial and error was that config.assets.debug = false was causing me to not see an issue with my gem file setup. When I set it to true, the error I got pointed me to the fact that my 'bootstrap-sass' gem was inside my assets group when it should not have been.

So for those who have hit this issue and have made it all the way down to this comment, try setting config.assets.debug = true in your production environment to see if it will at least get you pointed in the right direction.